# How do third party libraries work with ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I am used to using the more popular CommonJS modules, where the process is:

- `yarn` or `npm` install the modules you need (typically to `node_modules`)
- `require` the modules you need in your front end code
- bundle your front end code into a single large file including all dependencies with `browserify` or a similar tool

I get with ES6 modules I use [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), but:

- Should my dependencies be downloaded to the local disk, or loaded from third party (official) URLs?
- Where and how can I get ES6 versions of popular libraries?
- If, like most libraries, there's a CommonJS but not an ES6 library, is there a way to use that?
- Do I still need to bundle? I'll be using HTTP/2 so my connection will be multiplexed

Thanks!

Comment: "*Should my dependencies be loaded from third party (official) URLs?*" - that's not exactly related to ES6, except perhaps in terms of availability. Whether to load libs from CDNs of your own servers depends on other factors. Notice that when using a CDN, you cannot take advantage of HTTP/2 push.

Comment: @Bergi Using a full URL or relative path is related to ES6 as in it's literally the thing that comes after `import  (whatever) from`

Comment: Oh, *that* is what you are getting at. However you could use a build chain that resolves any string to any file, and then spits out a relative or absolute link to something on your server or one someone else's server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a couple of hours nobody has answered this, and I've got things working:

- Your dependencies are generally downloaded to the local disk. Typically to a `/public/js/thirdparty` folder or similar.
- There's no tool to discovered and download CommonJS modules. You'll usually download whatever you can with a web browser, then edit them to remove UMD wrappers, and replace the (in the case of ImagesLoaded library) `return ImagesLoaded` with a `export default ImagesLoaded`
- To use the third party modules, `import` them. To use the default `import imagesLoaded from "/js/thirdparty/imagesloaded.pkgd.js";`
- You can bundle if you want, but if you're using ES6 modules you're probably supporting new browsers which also allow parallel downloads via HTTP/2

Comment: Instead of removing UMD (and other) wrappers by hand, you might consider building the respective libraries from their sources yourself. Often they already use some module system already, and are wrapped only for distribution. A custom build might give you a reproducible ES6 bundle.